# pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PhoneCodeInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PHONE_CODE_INVALID] - The confirmation code is invalid

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PhoneCodeInvalid: Telegram says: [400 PHONE_CODE_INVALID] - The confirmation code is invalid (caused by "auth.SignUp")

When I want to sign up it says confirmation code is invalid but I didn't even input the confirmation code. I've been searching for a long time and I asked everywhere except stackowerflow. Can somebody help ? :/

I got the confirmation code btw but I can't input it. It gives this error and after that it sends the confirmation code.

```
app = Client(name=number, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_pass, phone_number=number)

app.connect()

sent_code = app.send_code(phone_number=number)

app.sign_up(phone_number=number, phone_code_hash=sent_code.phone_code_hash, first_name = "dsadadsad", last_name = "asdadsa")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take confirmation code as input, then pass it in code.

```
client = Client(f"sessions/{phone}", api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()

sent_code = client.send_code(phone)

code = input("Enter the code : ")

signed_in = client.sign_in(phone, sent_code.phone_code_hash, code)
```